# Problem creating a post with object_id property using the JavaScript SDK and the graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, photos

After uploading a photo to an album that was created for my app, i want to create a post with that photo by using its id as a value of object_id. The photo gets uploaded, the post gets created, but there is no sign of the photo within the post. I have permissions for publish_steam and read_stream. Here is the code i´m using:

```
var params = {};
params['url'] = "http://some.url/image.jpg";
params['message'] = "some message entered by user";
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', params, function(response){
            if(!response){
                console.log('no response after photos post');
                }
            else if(response.error){
                console.log('response error');
                }
            else{
                var photo_id = response.id;
                console.log('response ok after post');
                FB.api('/me/feed/','post',
                   {
                     name: 'App-Name',
                     link: 'http://url_to_my_app_on_facebook'
                     caption: 'caption_for_my_app',
                     description: 'description_for_my_app'
                     message: 'some message entered by user',
                     object_id: parseInt(photo_id),
                   },
                   function(response) {
                     if (!response) {
                       console.log('no response after feed post');
                     } else {
                       console.log('post was created');
                     }
                   }
                 );
            }
        });
```

This should work, right? Maybe you guys can give me heads up where i went wrong...

Answer (score -1):

Kaffeedraft

Your app will need user_photos permissions if you do not already have, you will also need to use a user access token.

1. Refer to http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/
2. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums
   to test scope for access.
3. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#connections
   for permission need for connections.